# After resizing/expanding div size, while releasing action it comes back to its default size

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to click and hold resizable handler and then moving mouse by x and y offset and then releasing the mouse to expand div. 
After releasing the Action div comes back to its Default size.

I ll appreciate even if I get JavascriptExecutor equivalent script as well.

Here is my code snippet.

```
new Actions(driver)
    .clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-qa-ref='resize-handle-NE']/div")))
    .moveByOffset(50,-50)
    .release()
    .build()
    .perform();
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML for this resizable DIV to your question? Nothing looks wrong with the Java code you posted. My only guess is the element you are clicking on isn't the one JavaScript is expecting, so things are behaving wonky.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Outer Div is : ```<div data-qa-ref="resize-handle-NE" class="src-hellospa-components-editor-handle-index__resizeHandle--2KIOH src-hellospa-components-editor-handle-resize-handle__resizeHandle--2_F5u src-hellospa-components-editor-handle-resize-handle__handleNE--3Q7z_"><div class="src-hellospa-components-editor-handle-resize-handle__dot--IKsBi"></div></div>``` and InnerDiv is ```<div class="src-hellospa-components-editor-handle-resize-handle__dot--IKsBi"></div>``` . I have updated my code snippet with relative xpath.

Comment: Please add the code to your question, not as a comment.